# Clear Mapbox-gl fog effect

Tags: mapbox-gl

I've created a Mapbox-gl map with a globe projection. I then use map.setFog({}) to add the fog effect.

Is there a way to clear the fog by changing the settings or remove it entirely from the map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to change/remove fog from map, if you want to remove fog completely just use **map.setFog(null)**.

**Note:** map.setFog({}) will set fog to mapbox default fog settings.